# Mostrar API Json en HTML

Tags: json, api

Asi que necesito ayuda con este codigo

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>fetch('https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/88.14.147.105')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
          var divOut = document.getElementById('txtOut');
          var allStudents = myJson.students;
          var txtOut = "";
          for (var k in allStudents) {
            txtOut += `<b>${ping}</b><br />`;
            txtOut += `Jugadores: ${players}<br />`;
          }
          divOut.innerHTML = txtOut;
        });</script>
        <div id="txtOut"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Estoy usando esta API: https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/88.14.147.105
Esta es la respuesta

```
{"ip":"88.14.147.105","port":25565,"debug":{"ping":true,"query":false,"srv":false,"querymismatch":false,"ipinsrv":false,"cnameinsrv":false,"animatedmotd":false,"cachetime":1608836107,"apiversion":2},"motd":{"raw":["\u00a7f\u00a7k\u00a7l1\u00a7r\u00a73\u00a7l SERVIDOR SURVIVAL\u00a7r\u00a7f\u00a7k\u00a7l 1\u00a7r","\u00a7r\u00a76Mantenido por\u00a7r\u00a72\u00a7o\u00a7l Lhetro\u00a7r\u00a7o\u00a7l","\u00a7r\u00a74\u00a7k\u00a7o\u00a7l---------------------------\u00a7r"],"clean":["1 SERVIDOR SURVIVAL 1","Mantenido por Lhetro","---------------------------"],"html":["<span style=\"color: #FFFFFF\"><span class=\"minecraft-formatted--obfuscated\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">1<\/span><\/span><\/span><span style=\"color: #00AAAA\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> SERVIDOR SURVIVAL<\/span><\/span><span style=\"color: #FFFFFF\"><span class=\"minecraft-formatted--obfuscated\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> 1<\/span><\/span><\/span>","<span style=\"color: #FFAA00\">Mantenido por<\/span><span style=\"color: #00AA00\"><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\"> Lhetro<\/span><\/span><\/span><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"><\/span>","<span style=\"color: #AA0000\"><span class=\"minecraft-formatted--obfuscated\"><span style=\"font-style: italic;\"><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">---------------------------<\/span><\/span><\/span><\/span>"]},"players":{"online":0,"max":7},"version":"1.16.3","online":true,"protocol":753,"icon":"data:image\/png;base64,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","software":"Paper"}
```

Lo unico que quiero conseguir mostrar es Ping, en este casoes Ping:true, me da igual si lo muestro como true o le puedo cambiar el texto.
Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Una vez tienes tu json 'myJson' puedes jugar con él.
Pongo el 'script' separado para que se vea qué es body, y qué parte el script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>The response</h1>
  <div id="txtOut"></div>
</body>

<script>
  fetch('https://api.mcsrvstat.us/2/88.14.147.105')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    var divOut = document.getElementById('txtOut');
    txtOut = ""
    txtOut += `<p>Lucky me! Version: <b>${myJson.version}</b></p>`;
    txtOut += `<p>To be or not to be? <b>${myJson.debug.ping ? "It's fine" : "No, it isn't."}</b></p>`;
    txtOut += `<p>There are <b>${myJson.players.online}</b> player(s) online.</p>`;
    if (myJson.players.online != 0 && myJson.players.online >= 1) {
      txtOut += `<table>`;
      txtOut += `<thead>`;
      txtOut += `<tr>`;
      txtOut += `<th>Name</th>`;
      txtOut += `<th>(tab)</th>`;
      txtOut += `<th>UUID</th>`;
      txtOut += `</tr>`;
      txtOut += `</thead>`;
      txtOut += `<tbody>`;
      myJson.players.list.forEach ( (luser) => {
        txtOut += `<tr>`;
        txtOut += `<td>${luser}</td>`;
        txtOut += `<td>--></td>`;
        txtOut += `<td>${myJson.players.uuid[luser] || "Not available"}</td>`;
        txtOut += `</tr>`;
      });
      txtOut += `</tbody></table>`;
    }
    divOut.innerHTML = txtOut;
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué estás interpretando toda la respuesta de la API? En la pregunta se aclara que solamente se quiere obtener 1 valor. En estos casos conviene tener una respuesta lo más limpia posible... Además, ¿en qué fallaba la pregunta? Porque tu código lo veo bien, pero no me queda claro qué corregiste

Comment: En la pregunta utiliza 'myJson.students' (que no veo en la respuesta JSON) y utiliza 'players' sin haberlo declarado como variable. Por lo tanto, son datos que no puede sacar desde su código y conducen a error. Por ese motivo añado cómo mostrar un componente del raiz, como 'myJson.version', cómo jugar a mostrar un texto en función de si quiere interpretar ese 'true/flase' desde 'myJson.debug.ping', como sacar los datos de un array (matriz) siendo 'myJson.players.list' el listado de jugadores, y 'myJson.players.uuid[luser]' la manera de llegar al elemento concreto dentro de un diccionario.

Comment: @Pollo tiene razón cuando dice que el elemento se puede consultar desde `${myJson.debug.ping}` y dar por finalizada la contestación.
Pero la etiqueta `<div id="txtOut"></div>` se genera con posterioridad al 'script', lo que implica que ningún valor será mostrado. Por ese motivo modifiqué las partes del código (primero body y luego el script) y las aclaraciones del comentario anterior.